# Shopify Hide Best Sellers

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to hide access from competition viewing the best-sellers, specifically using a URL like this:

www.store.myshopify.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling

I've tried `{% if collection.url contains 'sort_by=best-selling' %}` but that doesn't work.  Is there any way to target a URL with an attached query string?

If not, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `collection.url` doesn't return the query string, in your example, it would output `/collections/all`

I don't think there's a way in Liquid to get the current url query string. You can only set the default sort type with `collection.default_sort_by : 'price'` 
Or to override all sorting with `{% assign products = collection.products | sort: 'price' %}`

You can override the `sort_by` query string parameter using jQuery to substitute `best-selling` by `price`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return results[1] || 0;
    }

    var sort_by = $.urlParam('sort_by');
    if(sort_by == "best-selling") {
        var url = window.location.href;
        url = url.replace("best-selling", "price"); // override to sort by price
        window.location.href = url; // redirect to url
    }
<script>
```

Using this code with your example, it would automatically redirect the page `www.store.myshopify.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling` to `www.store.myshopify.com/collections/all?sort_by=price`

But keep in mind that your competitors could disable that JS code and still access the best-selling items.